# Bookshelf.js Not connecting to the correct host?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, knex.js

I am working on a express.js application that has been dockerized. Here is the config information I give to bookshelf.

```
{
    "database_dev" : {
        "client": "mysql",
        "connection": {
            "host": "DB",
            "database": "TERRA_DEV",
            "user": "dev",
            "port": "3306",
            "password": "goon",
            "charset": "utf8",
            "host": ""
        }
    },

    "database_test" : {
        "client": "mysql",
        "connection": {
            "host": "DB",
            "database": "TERRA_TEST",
            "user": "tester",
            "port": "3306",
            "password": "goon",
            "charset": "utf8",
            "host": ""
        }
    },
....
```

Here is my docker-compose.test.yml I am running to try and execute my tests.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
services:
 sut:
     build: .
     command: npm test
     depends_on:
         - web
 web:
    build: .
    command: "npm start"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - DB
    networks:
        - web_sql_bridge

 redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
        - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
        - '6379:6379'
 DB:
     image: mysql:5.7
     restart: always
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="goon"
         - MYSQL_DATABASE="TERRA_TEST"
         - MYSQL_DATABASE="TERRA_DEV"
         - MYSQL_USER="tester"
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD="goon"
     ports:
         - "3306:3306"
     networks:
         - web_sql_bridge
volumes:
    appconf:

networks:
  web_sql_bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
sut_1    |     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
sut_1    |     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
sut_1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
sut_1    |     --------------------
sut_1    |     at Protocol._enqueue (/TerraServer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
sut_1    |     at Protocol.handshake (/TerraServer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
sut_1    |     at Connection.connect (/TerraServer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
```

So basically as you can see from up above I have a config.json with some database information that I get in a JS file and give it to bookshelf.js as an argument. This is used in my mocha tests where is throws the error I posted. The error seems to indicate it trying to connect to 127.0.0.1. Why is bookshelf.js trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 when I give it DB?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it looks odd to me that 'web' is on the 'web_sql_bridge' but 'DB' is not.  I would think they can't communicate, but I am not sure.

Comment: @emory If you scroll down, DB has a networks section for web_sql_bridge.

Comment: you are right.  I did not notice the code was scrollable.  Sorry for the false tip.

Comment: why do you publish the ports DB ports "3306:3306"?  Shouldn't that be unnecessary? (unrelated to your problem)

Comment: why do you publish the ports DB ports "3306:3306"?  Shouldn't that be unnecessary? (unrelated to your problem)

Comment: @emory Not sure, I will probably clean it up once I get it working correctly.

Comment: Does it work when you start the mysql manually, wait a bit and then start your app, it could be the that your mysql container isn't fully started (although the container is started, the mysql service inside is maybe still starting), and your app tries to connect already while the mysql service is not avaiable.

Comment: another remark. I see ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 while it should not connect to localhost (because your app is running in a container too, the log should show DB:3306)

Comment: Bookshelf uses Knex.js for connecting, it doesn't manage the connection itself, so this should be a Knex question. That said, are you sure the host `DB` is reachable from your application server?

Comment: @devius I changed the tag from bookshelf.js to knex.js, also how could I tell if host DB is reachable? Would I start the container normally without the tests and then try to login through MySQL CLI while in the container?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Turns out I needed to run.

```
docker system prune -a
```

When I would build for a second time it would not update the files and my config file was behind in the image but not my repo where it pulls the code.

and also removed the quotes around the DB enviroment.

```
DB:
     image: mysql:5.7
     restart: always
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=goon
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=TERRA_TEST
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=TERRA_DEV
         - MYSQL_USER=tester
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=goon
```